# mips associative floating point

Tags: mips, floating

okay just for testing i have this code

```
    .data
    # This shows you can use a .word and directly encode the value in hex
    # if you so choose
num1:   .word 0x3F800000
num2:   .float 1234.567


num3: .float 45.67834
num4: .float 0.0004
result: .word 0
string: .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main:
    la $t0, num1
    lwc1 $f2, 4($t0)
    lwc1 $f4, 8($t0)
    lwc1 $f6, 12($t0)


    # Print out the values of the summands

    li $v0, 2
    mov.s $f12, $f2
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, string
    syscall

    li $v0, 2
    mov.s $f12, $f4
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, string
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, string
    syscall

    # Do the actual addition

    add.s $f12, $f2, $f6
    add.s $f12, $f12, $f4


    # Transfer the value from the floating point reg to the integer reg

    swc1 $f12, 8($t0)
    lw $s0, 8($t0)

    # At this point, $f12 holds the sum, and $s0 holds the sum which can
    # be read in hexadecimal

    li $v0, 2
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, string
    syscall

    # This jr crashes MARS
    # jr $ra
```

i have this

```
    add.s $f12, $f2, $f6
    add.s $f12, $f12, $f4
```

i tried swapping the order to say

```
    add.s $f12, $f4, $f6
    add.s $f12, $f12, $f2
```

but the result is the same

i checked wikipedia for examples of floating point additions which arent the same, but this always comes to 1280.2457

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

they had this happen:

```
 a = 1234.567, b = 45.67834, c = 0.0004
 (a + b) + c:
     1234.567   (a)
   +   45.67834 (b)
   ____________
     1280.24534   rounds to   1280.245
    1280.245  (a + b)
   +   0.0004 (c)
   ____________
    1280.2454   rounds to   1280.245  <--- (a + b) + c
 a + (b + c):
   45.67834 (b)
 +  0.0004  (c)
 ____________
   45.67874
   1234.567   (a)
 +   45.67874 (b + c)
 ____________
   1280.24574   rounds to   1280.246 <--- a + (b + c)
```

didn't hapepn for me it just works with any values I try

Answer (score 0):

nm, i got it

```
a=0.00004
b=45.67840
c=1234.567
```